# Windows findstr with AND condition?

Tags: windows, find, windows-command-prompt, findstr

Is it possible, in one line, without a batch file to use findstr and only return a 0 %errorlevel% if all of the strings are found?

I am doing a gem list, which lists out a bunch of gems.  I then want to use findstr/find to make sure that EACH string I search for exists.  If one of them do not, then it should return a non 0 error code.  Currently it will always return a 0 error code if any of the strings are found.  It seems to work great with OR conditions, but not AND conditions.  How can I do this?

C:... gem list | findstr "A B C D"

I only want a return code of 0 if it finds ALL of those.  If D does not exist, it will still print out A B C, which gives the error code of 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of the "gem list" command? Is it one gem per line, or is it a single space-delimited line of gems?

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR %G IN (foo, bar) DO (gem list | findstr %G)
```

Now if I can just get it to hold on to the error code for each return.

A better way to handle it and error if one of the commands in the loop fails:

```
FOR %G IN (foo, foobar) DO (gem list | findstr %G) || IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 exit
```

Then it will always return a non , giving you the correct errorlevel on exit